# Error installing express.js application Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to install Express.js in Node.js for make web application, but while installing it gives some error.

I already installed `package.json` and I have the `node_modules` paste, but even so, it doesn't work when I try to use express binary module to locally initialize my application.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "jade": "^1.11.0",
    "package.json": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "version": ""
}
```

My code in the cmd :

```
express my_app
create : my_app
create : my_app/package.json
create : my_app/app.js
create : my_app/public
create : my_app/public/javascripts
create : my_app/public/images
create : my_app/public/stylesheets
create : my_app/public/stylesheets/style.css
create : my_app/routes
create : my_app/routes/index.js
create : my_app/views
create : my_app/views/layout.jade
create : my_app/views/index.jade
```

I am using Windows,and because of that, programming in Node.js in this system operational is really bad. He doesn't recognizes the `create` command and returns the error, saying that can't create the `my_app` application. How can I make that work ?

Comment: after npm install express do you have access to the express command in terminal?

Comment: So guys, he installed now the my_app.js aplication, but he didn't installed everything. Still giving me the same error, but the difference is that now he installed some part of what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing express globally on your system. This can be done by running `npm i express -g`. Also, try running `./node_modules/.bin/express my_app` instead of `express my_app`